# making a jquery validate rule with regex

Tags: regex, jquery-validate

I am trying to make a jquery validate rule that looks for a specific value pattern. However I am having problems where I get false positives.

here is my rule

```
Query.validator.addMethod("eidFormat", function (value, element) {
    var a1formatChk = /[^b-z]\d{5}|\d{6}$/.test(value);
    return e1formatChk;
}, "Your oder code needs to be your employee id. Please try again.");
```

the value I am looking for needs to be a and 5 or 6 digits. Also I am adding the rule on field change. either they need to add their employee id or leave the filed blank and I add a system generated id on the back end.

here is the problem I am having

if I enter b1234 it fails and gives me the message
but if I put in garbage like fgkhjkjfhg54645 the test comes back true.

I am thinking this is more a reg ex pattern issue, but am not sure.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `[^b-z]` would match any character(including non-word character) but not of `b` to `z`. So change your regex to,

```
^a\d{5,6}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `a` Matches a literal a.
- `\d{5,6}` would allow 5 or 6 digits.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: thank you that worked. I am using w3school for regex pattern writing. is there a good blog or site that goes in to detail?